# population of dots with normal distribution of pitch

Tags: normal-distribution, computational-geometry, packing-problem

I want to generate a plot that shows a rectangle populated with dots, where the dot-to-dot distance (pitch) distribution is a lognormal (or a gaussian). I want to be able to change the mean dot-to-dot distance and also the sigma.
I started with the line below, which generates randomly placed points.

```
Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Black, 
  Point /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4000, 2}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

The following line seem to generate a normal distribution for the dot location in the square instead of normalDistribution of the dot-to-dot distance.

```
Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Black, 
  Point /@ RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {4000, 2}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

I'd really appreciate some help. 
Also in the lines above, I set the number of dots to 4000, but I guess the number must depend on the Rectangle size and the mean dot to dot distance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Putting aside the issue of how to do this in Mathematica, do you know how do distribute the points mathematically?

Comment: What is the "dot to dot" distance? The distance from a dot to its nearest neighbour or to all other dots?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the questioner means the distances between every possible pair of dots.  Note, though, that this distribution can never be Gaussian, since a Gaussian always has probability mass at negative values.

Comment: I am going to migrate this question to [Math.SE].  If and when you have an algorithm you wish to implement please post here again and we will help if we are able.

Comment: The dot-to-dot distance (or pitch) is the distance to nearest neighbours (as Simon Woods wrote). @ David G.: the distribution can be gaussian centered to the mean pitch value which is !=0.